# Can anybody explain what a t-SNE visualization or graph on a word2vec model signifies?

Tags: data-visualization, data-science, word2vec, word-embedding

Can we take the stand that the words around the target word have an impact on it in a positive or negative way or is there any other kind of interpretation.

A t-SNE graph is given at the end of the page in the link provided for reference. Thank you.

https://www.kaggle.com/pierremegret/gensim-word2vec-tutorial?source=post_page-----a38bf1906483----------------------#Getting-Started